# Android Cursor.registerContentObserver()

Tags: android, cursor

I am using a couple of listviews, each using a subclasses SimpleCursorAdapter to deal with results from a db. It's a simple diary viewer, activity 1 = day, activity 2 = week.

I am trying to delete an item in the day listview, and then have both the day and week views to refresh following the change.

If I call cursor.requery() in the activity I have deleted in, it reflects the change. However, the other activity doesn't know of the change.

I think I want to use Cursor.registerContentObserver as the docs claim "Register an observer that is called when changes happen to the content backing this cursor. Typically the data set won't change until requery() is called."

However, I naively wrote a content observer :

```
private class dbObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public dbObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        lectureCursor.requery();
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }

}
```

Then in the onCreate of each activity :

```
dbObserver test = new dbObserver(new Handler());
    lectureCursor.registerContentObserver(test);
```

But onChange is never being called when I delete from the database. Am I doing something stupid here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason why it doesn't work is because you are attempting to call requery() from within the onChange() but onChange() is only **after** requery() is called.

You may want to consider using the ContentResolver's [registerContentObserver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html). This way onChange() will get called whenever there is a change on the db for that uri.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean - I'm not using a ContentResolver. My activities directly get a cursor from my DB, and I was trying to use Cursor.registerContentObserver and pass in a custom observer to cause requerying... Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: I didn't realize you were not using a content provider. From the api description, it says that onChange will likely not get called until requery() is called. The only place you call it is within your onChange() but that won't get called unless requery() is called. So you have a cyclical problem. Maybe you should just call requery() every time you attempt to populate your views?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out you need to call:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

To make cursor notify your observer about changes.